# Powershell systeminfo as JSON or XML

Tags: json, xml, powershell, scripting

I am executing:

```
   systeminfo | ConvertTo-Json 

   "Host Name:                 namehere",
   "OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise",
    ...
```

but I need

```
   "Host Name":                 "namehere",
   "OS Name":                   "Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise",
    ...
```

The following command gives a similar issue

```
systeminfo | ConvertTo-Xml -As String

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Objects>
  <Object Type="System.String"></Object>
  <Object Type="System.String">Host Name:                 namehere</Object>
  <Object Type="System.String">OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise</Object> "
```

but I need something like:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <HostName>namehere</HostName>
    <OSName>Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise</OSName> 
    ...
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this:

```
systeminfo /fo CSV | ConvertFrom-Csv
```

or

```
systeminfo /fo CSV | ConvertFrom-Csv | convertto-json
```

Answer (score 3):

To complement [thom schumacher's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49437946/45375):

**In PSv5+ you can alternatively use [`Get-ComputerInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-computerinfo)**.

While the field (property) names in the resulting `[Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ComputerInfo]` instance aren't identical to the ones in `systeminfo`'s output, you're likely to get *additional* information there.

Since `Get-ComputerInfo` outputs an *object* whose properties contain the information, you can send that *directly* to `ConvertTo-Json` / `ConvertTo-Xml`

```
Get-ComputerInfo | ConvertTo-Json
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

External programs such as `systeminfo` can only output *text*, and often do so in (semi-)*unstructured* form that is more geared toward human viewing than further programmatic processing.

By contrast, in order to get meaningful output from `ConvertTo-Json` / `ConvertTo-Xml`, you need either a *structured* text format - which `systeminfo` happens to offer via its `/FO` option - or input *objects*, which is what you get PowerShell's cmdlets output.

Therefore, it's usually better to look for PowerShell alternatives to external programs; if their are none, and if the external programs don't offer structured-text output, you have to resort to doing your own text-parsing in order to impose structure, which can be both brittle and cumbersome.